# Child not executing `scanf` function

Tags: c

I don't know if it's a parent/child issue or not but it seems like the `scanf` is just getting skipped since everything before and after it is working fine.

```
int main() {
int randomnumber = 1+ rand() % 51;
pid_t pid=fork();
int fd[2];
int fd2[2];
pipe(fd);
pipe(fd2);

if(pid<0){
    printf("Fork failed");
}

if(pid==0){
printf("Enter your guess: \n");
}

while(1)
{

if(pid==0){
 int sign;  //ignore everything related to the sign for now as I still didn't fully finish the code but I don't think that is related to my issue. 
 int guess;
 scanf("%d", &guess);   //This isn't executing
 puts("test"); //this got executed normally
 close(fd[0]);
 write(fd[1], &guess, sizeof(int));
 close(fd2[1]);
 read(fd2[0], &sign, sizeof(int));  
}

    if(pid>0){

    int signal=1;
    close(fd2[0]);
    int checker;
    close(fd[1]);
    read(fd[0], &checker, sizeof(int));


    if(checker>randomnumber){
        printf("Guess should be lower");
        signal=1;
        write(fd2[1], &signal, sizeof(int));
    }

    if(checker<randomnumber){
        printf("Guess should be higher");
        signal=1;
        write(fd2[1], &signal, sizeof(int));
    }

    if(checker==randomnumber){
        signal=0;
        write(fd2[1], &signal, sizeof(int));
        printf("WIN");
        break;
    }
}
}
return 1;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem here is that you call `pipe` *after* calling `fork`, so instead of two pipes that the parent and child can use to communicate, you end up with 4 -- 2 (just) in the parent, and 2 just in the child.  Then, in the parent, when you call close(fd[1]), that closes the write end of that pipe, so the following read immediately returns an EOF.

So the scanf in the child is working just fine, you just never notice it, because the parent has already continued past the read into the checks, which likely fail, but then the parent dies with a SIGPIPE trying to write to fd2[1] when the read end has already been closed.

If you move the fork after the pipe calls, things will be better, but you'll still be confused by the fact that you aren't seeing any messages from the parent.  That's because your printf lines have no newlines, so they just write into the stdout buffer without actually flushing things.  Add a newline (or explicit fflush) and you'll see the messages.